# Does the set of all continuous functions from $x$ to $y$ uniquely determine a topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $x,y$ be arbitrary sets and $T_x, T_y$ topologies on $x,y$ respectively. Suppose we are given a set $\mathcal{C}_{x\to y}$, of all continuous functions from $x$ into $y$. Can we deduce either $T_x$ or $T_y$? If so, how? Are the $T_x, T_y$ we deduce via this method unique? If not, is there an easy counterexample?

Note that I did come across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020370/deducing-a-topology-given-its-continuous-functions) post on MSE. However, Douglas is asking about topologies on $x,y$ that make a single function continuous whereas I am specifying precisely all those functions which are continuous and precisely all those which are not. There's also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890383/is-there-another-topology-on-mathbbr-that-gives-the-same-continuous-functio) post that seems to be addressing a variation of the specific case where $x=y=\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. whether or not two different topologies on $x,y$ can have identical sets of continuous functions).

Comment: What if $T_x$ is discrete? Then any function out of $T_x$ will be continuous.

Comment: As @CharlesHudgins points out, the answer is generally no.  If $T_x$ is discrete then $T_y$ could be anything.  Dually, if $T_y$ is indiscrete then $T_x$ could be anything.  You lose both ways.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins yes, indeed, but if $C$ does not contain every function $x\to y$, then we can rule out $T_x$ being discrete. I guess just knowing the set of all continuous functions from $x\to y$ can in some cases not suffice to determine $T_x,T_y$. I think it's an interesting question outside the trivial cases.

Comment: @quanticbolt: I think the question is interesting if you turn it round: are there any interesting general conditions on $T_x$ and $T_y$, which ensure that both $T_x$ and $T_y$ **are** determined by the set of continuous functions?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal C_{\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb Q}$ and $\mathcal C_{\Bbb R\to\Bbb N}$ both contain exactly the constant functions, and these topological spaces can be seen as the same $X$ and the same $Y$ with different topologies.

More generally, $\mathcal C_{\text{connected}\to\text{totally disconnected}}$  is the set of constant functions, whatever the topologies.

Comment: I don't understand what it means for these to be "seen as the same $X$ and the same $Y$ with different topologies."

Comment: @Randall The obvious thing: that topological spaces of the same cardinality may be seen as the same set with two different topologies, hence me referring to $\Bbb R^2$, $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb Q$ and (I had deleted it by mistake) $\Bbb N$ instead of going through the whole transfer(s) of structure(s).

Comment: To be noted that any transfer of structure preserves constant functions.